# Help understand phrase "to be engaged with one's kids in a meaningful way"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I recently encountered the following paragraph:

```
I try hard to become incredibly selective about those
things I engage with, so I can be really present for the stuff
that I’m doing, and be really engaged with my kids in a meaningful way.
```

In this context, what do the phrases

```
things I engage with
```

and

```
to be engaged with one's kids in a meaningful way
```

mean?

Comment: See **2.1** Meaning of [Engage with](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/engage?q=engage+with#engage__20)

Comment: @CarSmack It's kinda unclear. Could you give me some simple examples of usage of *to engage with*.

Answer (score 3):

See the definition for the *intransitive* verb here at 2.c:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engage?show=0&t=1413549624

*To engage with* means to "give your attention to {something|someone}".

To be *really engaged with* means to give something or someone your undivided attention.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that he is choosing not to focus or spend time on things that aren't that important to him. Since he's not focusing on those unimportant things, he can focus on his kids, converse with them, play with them, teach them things, etc.

For example, he could have chosen to just watch TV when he gets home from work. But instead, he chooses to keep the TV turned off and hang out with his kids.

Comment: The thing is that each of your and @TRomano answer adds to each other. His is more technical, yours is more context-based. So I don't want to mark one of them as accepted => it would not be honest.

Comment: @DenisKulagin That can happen a lot. You don't have to accept one, that's your choice. But I'd recommended just choosing one, flip a coin if you need to, just so people know you've already received decent answer to your question.